# Is there a way to edit a "mostly code" question?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I was trying to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755009/my-code-show-error-when-i-want-to-cancel-timer-help-please) (improving the title and tweaking the first sentence), but when I tried to submit my edit, I was stopped by this pop-up:

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

I'm not the asker (and know nothing about the language either), so I can't add any more details. Is there anything I can do to enable myself to edit it, or should I let it be?

Comment: That probably should have been flagged "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: there is no question there.

Comment: @ckuhn203 - Ha, fair enough; looking at it again, it isn't a good question. However, on the off-chance I run into the same situation again with a different question, I'd still be interested in an answer.

Comment: I got a similar (personal) issue with code-only *answers*, such as http://stackoverflow.com/a/23849764/2564301. This user in particular does not like to explain what changes to original code are made, or why the proposed code is "better". I stopped asking for this [about here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869471/need-to-use-recursive-solution-to-solve-this/20869580#comment31314236_20869580).

Comment: By editing it, you hit the filter that the OP was supposed to hit to stop him from posting that junk.  Some odds that the formatting problem was intentional, he just kept trying until it stopped blocking him.

Comment: I think because the original question, did not add these symbols: (```) at the end of their post, they were allowed to add a mostly code questions.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Asking a good question is the OP's job. It's not worth the effort to edit a question that's very likely to get closed for various close reasons. And then, the question you quote is not even a question.

What you (we) should do in cases like this is *ask for clarification* and if the OP doesn't respond to that, close/downvote. Editing is for making good (or at least reasonable) questions better, it's not for making up for the lack of effort the OP put into the question.

Comment: *+1*. Exactly. We don't need to go out of our way to edit poor questions into good ones. If the OP wants an answer and would like their question to remain open, *they* should put in efforts, not us. Anyone who has worked for more than a few minutes on this problem should be able to include a better description of it. "*This code work without timer cancel code*" is not even a question.

Comment: *"Editing is for making good (or at least reasonable) questions better..."* - I'm not sure about this. Is that Stack Overflow policy? (I try to salvage/improve non-good questions, so I'm concerned I might be violating SO policy).

Comment: @Gert - the question was not ***that*** bad. The biggest problem appeared to be English as a Second Language (ESL). Improving the title to summarize the problem, restating the titular question in the body and re-arranging the components so the error was listed earlier than the code appears to have salvaged the question (Petr reviously fixed some of the formatting issues). The question is now easy to read for an English speaker, and the answers provided by folks like Petr Abdulin still make sense.

Comment: What answers like this one usually leave out is a guideline what to do with posts "in between". This discussion is referenced by some duplicate-closed posts, so I'm not referring to the example of the OP of this meta thread, but to another post. I believe I'm not the only user who experiences this problem and doesn't decide towards **"close it because it is low quality [...]"** or **"don't edit it because it is pretty good the way it is and your edit contributes a negligible part"** - but one of the **cases in between.**

Comment: @AmalMurali I disagree with you. Several newbies don't know how to properly edit their posts. I was one of them. My first posts weren't properly formatted but someone else edited them for me. I learned the proper way to edit questions from looking at the edits others had made to my questions...

Comment: @Yatin That's Okay. Most users will understand that using all editing options properly takes some experience and they'll see that a poorly formatted question isn't necessarily a poor question entirely, the type Amal was referring to.

Answer (score 11):

There isn't much you can really do in these cases, unless you're a subject-matter expert who can have a go at reading the asker's mind and heavily revise the question. If you can do that, great! But then you wouldn't be seeing this error message.

Otherwise, editing these sorts of questions is colloquially referred to as "turd-polishing", which is a rude way of saying that it's wasted effort. Lipstick on a pig. **There's little point in taking the time to edit** (*especially* if you do not have full editing privileges, since your edits will need to be reviewed by several other community members) **if you can't actually fix the problems with the post by editing.**

Instead, simply flag these questions as being in need of closure. Obviously, pick the reason that you find to be most appropriate. In the specific situation that you describe, the odds are good that the most appropriate closure reason will be: off topic → lacks a clear problem statement or minimal reproducible example.

This will get the question placed "on hold" so that the asker can come back and edit it into shape, which is what really needs to happen.

Comment: What answers like this one usually leave out is a guideline what to do with posts "in between". This discussion is referenced by some duplicate-closed posts, so I'm not referring to the example of the OP of this meta thread, but to another post. I believe I'm not the only user who experiences this problem and doesn't decide towards **"close it because it is low quality [...]"** or **"don't edit it because it is pretty good the way it is and your edit contributes a negligible part"** - but one of the **cases in between.**

Answer (score 9):

I mostly concurr with [Gert Arnolds's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256093/3204551), especially that it is the OPs task to ask a good question.

But in such cases of blatant misuse, immediate down-voting/close-voting/delete-voting and moving on is indicated. Don't wait for that.

You might want to add a comment directing him to browse the help center if it seems one of his first questions.
More specific comments what he did wrong is always good as well, though he might not always appreciate it.

Comment: The question was good by stack overflow standards; it was just poorly presented. The question had a problem statement in the title, it had the relevant code, and it had a trace. The question needed formatting for the source code code and a few other minor corrections. I'm not sure I would claim blatant misuse. It looks more like English as a Second Language and unfamiliarity with the site (he is a new user). If the site made a better effort, then source code formatting issue might have been a non-issue.

Comment: And here's an example of *"If the site made a better effort"*: [Filter Questions and Answers for tab character?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261493/608639). But those proposals and initiatives have been killed by the community. So the community is kind of getting what it deserves.

Comment: Well, your feature-request was shot down. It might be worthwhile, but I'm not sure a block is really the right thing there, a warning though certainly is.

Comment: And regarding that question: Yes, it could be edited into shape. But, as is, it was *not* acceptable, and downvoting and closing until it was edited in shape was the right thing to do. I'm not sure it's good enough now, but its certainly above my shoot-it-now-threshold.

Comment: I had a similar problem trying to edit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989679/linker-error-while-building-qt-5-6-2-with-vs2015/44989908#44989908 and suggested the OP reformat their question, then happened to notice one of the root causes late in the pile of stuff they'd posted.  I would have been able to write my answer sooner if I'd been able to "fix" their post...

Answer (score 7):

The restriction is intended to prevent people from copying entire source files into a question with little or no explanation. As a result, questions that don't [include some context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156643/1438) are blocked. By extension, there's not much point in minor edits when a question is little more than a code dump. Improving the grammar of the prose, adding more code formatting, removing "thanks, and so on doesn't really fix the big problem.

However, building a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the original poster, would be a pretty great edit. Who knows? You might even be able to provide an answer after cutting out the cruft.

Comment: Funny situation is that the questioner was actually allowed to ask a question which can't be edited by users with more reputation. When I read a post and find myself wasting time on understanding, if I cleared out for myself, than I always leave an edit for those who can answer (even if I can't). In this case it was a wrong tag which is actually misleading.