# Why can't I edit questions?

Tags: support, edits

When I tried to edit [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/25699689/use-of-just-whilex) question, it showed

> it looks like your edit is mostly code; please add some more details.

All I did was added backticks and also improved a bit of grammar. The question is clear and on-topic. So,why does SO not allow me to do that?

I Googled and found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256092/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-mostly-code-question). But it explains that, the question mentioned in it was an unclear question .

So, is there any way I can edit such questions?

EDIT:[@AstroCB](http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/3366929/astrocb) edited that question.

Comment: Why edit instead of flagging to close? It doesn't show research effort, is too broad, dumps code...

Comment: @Anonymous , It is not at all too broad(half the answer is enough to explain it),does not dump too much code(It is readable too),searching `while(x)` does not provide enough info.Besides, He still asked a clear question(first post on SO)

Comment: @JonEricson , I have already explained why the post which you marked as duplicate isn't applicable here as the post which I linked doesn't lack effort.

Comment: I saw that, but I don't understand why this question is different. The block is automated. It has no way to differentiate between a clear and an unclear question. It's almost always useful to add a bit more prose to explain what sort of answer the code is prompting.

Comment: @JonEricson ,I cannot see the post linked in the duplicate because its deleted.But reading the answers and comments of the duplicate post tells that It was an unclear one.But here,OP has posted code and has also explained what is unclear to him. So it is not an unclear one like the post linked in the duplicate. My question here is in the title same as the duplicate post but the answer I expect is not the one as in the duplicate