# Unable to edit older posts that have a lot of code

Tags: support, bug, edits, suggested-edits

I've stumbled upon an older post that seemed like a decent question but required some major polishing in terms of grammar and wording. The post had a lot of code so after editing I realized I cannot submit it since SO told me that it has too much code.

It is not up to me to remove all the supplied code, so is there a way around this?

Comment: Link? Users with edit privileges have fewer restrictions than suggested edits.

Comment: Why do you have a lot of words capitalized in the title of this post?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to edit a "mostly code" question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256092/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-mostly-code-question)

Comment: @CoolGuy I think the OP was going for title-casing. Of course, this is not the norm on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young , One guy fixed the casing in the title and the OP reverted the changes made... I've rolled back the changes now

Comment: I have had this problem regarding too much code as well. But this has been answered multiple times on Meta