# "It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details"

Tags: support, edits, quality-filter, error-message

After editing my post, Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to submit it.

> It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details

I have added some code and modified several parts of it, but the post cannot be submitted. It is fine if this message appears when asking a new question, but it appears when I am trying to resubmit my edited post.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Which post?  And what was your edit (how did your post change as a result)?

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845594/intent-fragment-to-fragment). It been marked as duplicated.

Comment: Well...the system isn't lying...

Comment: It is mostly code now, in fact there are literally 7 non-code words in that post. And you are trying edit it to explain why it isn't a duplicate?  What are you trying to edit it?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I have added some code and would like to post my latest error.

Comment: @Hoo so you are trying to add more code?  That's your problem then.  You are probably right under the threshold that triggers that filter.  And by adding more, you are pushing yourself over the threshold.  You need to expand your explanation to explain what you are trying to do more clearly.  Posts that are almost all code are rarely useful.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for your response. It seems like I have to create another post in order to get my problem solved.

Comment: @Hoo No. You really do just need to add more information to the existing post (along with the updated code). If you re-post what you're trying to submit now, the code/text ratio will still be off.

Comment: @PaulRoub But I already add everything .

Comment: @Hoo asking a 2nd question about the same (or similar) problem is rarely useful (it will usually be a duplicate), especially when you don't have an answer to your original question.  I seems like writing English is something you are not comfortable doing, but you should work on it and make an effort.  Users are usually happy to help fix your grammar, but we can't do that if you don't write anything

Comment: I will try and expand my explanation :)

Comment: Related: [Cannot edit post due to code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336496/8117067) (As far as I understand, not a duplicate, because this question is from the original asker's perspective, while the linked question is from a random editor's perspective.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to edit a "mostly code" question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256092/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-mostly-code-question)

Comment: just upload to github and post a link

Comment: @java-addict301 No, if your code is all in an external link your question will get closed. The relevant code needs to be *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> How can I solve this?

Well, how about adding more details. Like, what are you trying to accomplish, how are you doing it, what difficulties you have found with the approach, another approaches you have tried, etc. In summary, without code isn't a good question neither is with just code. Search for the balance!

Comment: @A_J see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332769/7107445. Once you get 2k rep, you'll be able to edit other people's posts without issue. I am a bit disappointed by the limitation as well (fixing up someone's question so it's able to be understood), but I guess it makes sense to reduce suggested-edit queues from bad edits.

Comment: How the heck am I supposed to fabricate more details to someone else's post? In my case I'm just move the English portion to the top, above the code and add some sentences structure so that it's readable. I can't magically invent more about what the poster wants...

Comment: @Chrips "After edited ***my post***, Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to submit."

Comment: did someone know about the number? number of details in characters or words?

Comment: I tried adding text till I'm blue in the face but I still can't get rid of this message.

Comment: Sometimes it is difficult to add relevant details.

Comment: @OSGIJava then ask for guidance on that. There are many questions about "how to fix X", not many "how to find out what is causing X".

Comment: terrible! this just encourages users to post code without formatting it as such!

Answer (score 3):

1. Make the code sections smaller by removal of imports, comments, code sections that are not critical. If needed make a hard choice and remove the least important code.
2. Then when others ask questions, answer the questions inline but also update your original post with the details. Then you might be able to add more code to your original post.

I realize that this solution is not ideal, however it provides with practical steps. I hope others find it useful.

Comment: // , Or you can just add ..... after everything: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399401/2146138

Comment: @NathanBasanese That is really a terrible advice.

Comment: // , Yes. Yes it is.

Answer (score -5):

[image: check option code]

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, so can you explain?

Comment: The screenshot is from *[Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)*.

Comment: I am new here i have not used stackoverflow this is my first time solving question, Same problem i have faced. Just followed the mentioned instruction while posting question and issue get resolved for me.

Answer (score -40):

You have to add some more details about your question. In some cases there nothing more to add so give some dots after your details

eg: details about the questions ..........................................................................

** It's a quick fix that worked for me.

Comment: It's not a fix, but an attempt to get around the rules. It's also a possibly quick way to get downvotes.

Comment: I suspect you'll just find [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62910804/hdfs-dfsadmin-report-command-show-nothing-but-jps-command-shows-all-hadoop-daem) gets closed till you actually add those details.

Comment: I'm really curious to know if you were offered [this advice when you were creating your question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vawss.png) how you possibly can end up in a situation where you have to wiggle a post like you did. What is unclear in that guidance and how could we made that more helpful for you before you hit Review and Save?

Comment: You may as well just add "please downvote and close my question" instead, since that's basically what that tells me.

Comment: I also wonder.... wth is this answer not deleted? It's useless.

Comment: @10Rep Well it is some bad advice with a bunch of downvotes indicating that it is bad advice. So not necessarily useless.

Comment: @10Rep Deleting Answers on meta because one doesn't agree with them is not very useful at all. When it happens it depicts a non-existing "happy place" where everyone just agrees about everything and hides the truth that not everyone actually agrees. It's also called censorship and it's a slippery slope.

Comment: @Scratte Oh yeah, that is true...

Comment: // , Well, I guess that would technically work. Quite the hack fix, though.

Comment: @Scratte case in point, here, not because of the false appearance of agreement, but because of the sheer number of now-deleted answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354978/responding-to-the-lavender-letter-and-commitments-moving-forward

Comment: @NathanBasanese I don't understand what point you are trying to make. I can't see if there are any deleted Answers on that post, but I also cannot see any negatively scored non-deleted Answers.