# Trying to edit a question with the "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." error

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I, as other people (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256092/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-mostly-code-question) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310791/it-looks-like-your-post-is-mostly-code-please-add-some-more-details) ) ran into the problem that I could not edit a question, because the error "It look like your post is mostly code;  add some more details. " appeared.

The solution given to the other questioner was something along the lines: "You shouldnt bother editing a question with such a warning, as it is probably low quality and is going to be deleted".

While I  agree with the sentiment, I would really like to edit the typo out of the title of this, fairly popular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561332/what-is-order-of-execution-of-static-block-initialisatin-block-when-we-using-inh) (20 upvotes, 16k views) and, to be honest, don't quite understand why the error blocks me from doing so. It feels more like a bug than a feature, as I didn't change anything in the body.

Is there some reasoning on why I am blocked from editing the question title in such a case or is this unintended?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is intended that the error affects title edits.  If the post body has problems, and an edit ignore them, that edit is not very helpful even if it fixes other issues with title and tags.  Specifically, that edit fails to address all problems with the post and is incomplete.  You should suggest an edit that **fixes all aspects of the post**.  Improve both the title and add just a little bit more context to each code section of the question.

This restriction only applies to suggested edits, so any user with at least 2k reputation can freely edit posts such as this.  In the meantime, I have made an edit to the title while simultaneously rewording the final question in the body.

Comment: How can the editor add more non-code content though? We don't know what the OP's situation is.

Comment: @TheWanderer Notice that [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19561332/revisions) fixed a lot of misspellings and other confusing wording.  I didn't actually add any non-code content.  There's almost always something else to fix in edits.

Comment: But what if the question is just mostly unformatted code, and you want to fix that, along with a few typos? I've run into multiple 2-sentence questions with a stacktrace attached that don't let me edit.

Comment: @TheWanderer if there post is basically just a code dump with no context, close it as unclear or no MCVE.  Or ask for that information in comments.  There's nothing you can suggest at that point because the post is probably missing information.

Comment: @ryanyuyu But your edit still leave the question mostly code. A sub-2k user would probably not be able to make that edit.

Comment: @user202729 Are you referring to my edit to this question?  I'm not sure what you're saying, since I cleaned up the actual text of the question (English, title).  A sub-2k user can suggest the same edit that I made.

Comment: At the time you made the edit you have more than 2k right? I think that a sub 2k user cannot make the edit because the code-to-text ratio remains about the same as the original.

Comment: Not sure what the "too much code" threshold is, but I think the sheer size of the edit's diff might have been enough to get around that.  At least in this specific instance, the (meta) asker mentioned a title only edit instead of a substantial one so there's no way to know for sure if the edit restriction would have kicked in since they didn't actually make a complete edit. @user202729