# How to improve questions with too much (misformatted) code and too little non-code information?

Tags: discussion, edits

If a user has put more code in a question than normally allowed, but formatted incorrectly, how can we edit this post to correct the formatting?
The attempt to just format all the code correctly gives this error

> **It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.**

Then which type of info we edit. 
For example I provide a link:

[How to populate gridview with images based on spinner selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736404/how-to-populate-gridview-with-images-based-on-spinner-selection?rq=1).

How can I improve this?

Comment: I find it hard to really understand your question. Would you lilke to try rephrasing? I think giving some more introduction would help. The "more" at the start is one of the things which distract me.

Comment: Actually some times user can putted code in uncorrected formatted. If we edit these types of post then if user provide less info then how can i edit these types of posts.

Comment: I think you are referring to questions which only have enough non-code text because OP has misformatted most of the question, which actually consists mostly of code. A comment recommending to edit into correct formatting AND adding more explanation is probably the way to go. Maybe ask politely, whether OP has intentionally misformatted because of the warning. If you can argue that the question is too broad then use that close-vote/flag.

Comment: I am not sure that you and I have the same understanding of the word "less". To me it is the opposite of "more". You seem to be using it in the sense of "too little" or "more", the fact that I am not even sure about which one is part fo the confusion I mentioned.

Comment: @Yunnosch As you understand

Comment: means too little is used for less

Comment: I give a link please see this example and edit this

Comment: Did you try to format all code as "quote" AND "code"? If that works, the question is improved by at least using the same misformatting for everything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179726/discussion-between-shivam-kumar-and-yunnosch).

Comment: Could somebody else with <2k rep please try whether mis-formatting the question, but at least consistently, is possible? I do not want to try with my >10k privileges, I might succeed without it being helpful below 2k rep. If it works below 2k, then I think for the special case of the linked example, it would mean at least a little improvement of the question. I would like to add that to my answer, so I need somebody <2k to try. If somebody tries and succeeds, everybody else of course please look at the edit history to see OPs example.

Comment: I have edited your question for readability. Please let me know if I got something wrong.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes that's it. Thanks for editing and clearance

Comment: @AndrewT. yes i think but there are no example

Comment: @AndrewT. Now the post is edited with some user in my case that is not edited. Why

Comment: @Yunnosch is right about edit suggestion by <2k rep. This is one of many restrictions for those without full edit privilege (<2k rep).

Comment: Andrew has higher privileges. It is the reason why I asked people BELOW 2k to try and edit. Andrew chose to edit anyway. I am not surprised that he succeeded in editing where you (below 2k) could not.

Comment: @Yunnosch one more example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102634/open-a-new-xml-file-by-pressing-notification?rq=1 If i edit this then He says `Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are referring to questions which only have enough non-code text because the OP has misformatted most of the question, which actually consists mostly of code.

The problem in this case is that editing the question towards correct formatting is impossible, because of the warning about too little explanation with mostly code.

A comment (implicitly addressed at the OP) recommending to edit into correct formatting AND adding more explanation is probably the way to go. Maybe ask politely, whether the OP has intentionally misformatted because of the warning. The example question you linked, however, is so old that a reaction by the OP is unlikely.

If you can argue that the question is too broad then use that close-vote/flag.

(I asked for an experiment by a <2k user, to at least improve the question a little, by formatting consistently though still wrong. That experiment is now not possible anymore on the linked example question. If anybody finds a different similar question and could try with <2k, I would like to know the result. However, for users below 2k privileges, this kind of questions are best just left alone. This matches the answers on the duplicate question somebody has found by now.)

Comment: what is the meaning of OP

Comment: @ShivamKumar "Original Poster" (the person) or "Origianal Post" (the text). In the case of this meta question here: You. In the case of the linked example main question: Somebody else.

Comment: Related [meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332769/2821954): "*This restriction only applies to suggested edits, so any user with at least 2k reputation can freely edit posts such as this.*"