# SO allows to make text improvement, but I can't add some code "identation"

Tags: support, edits

I can see the point of not allowing only code editting, but take a look at this case. Im trying to make the question text more clear, and SO is allowing me to; but if I try to put the code in a "code sample" box, it says that the post is mostly code. I know this is, probably, a low quality question, but that can happens in others cases too.

**To be more clear, my point is: If some edit request is enough to meet the edition's requirement, why would put some additional stuff make it unacceptable?**

The original question:

[image: original question]

Edit without code identation:

[image: editting without change code identation]

Edit with code identation
[image]

Comment: You're showing only part of the question in those screenshots. If I had to guess, the remainder of the very long question is code. I would suggest rather than editing it, ask the OP to edit their own question to remove the irrelevant pieces of code. Also note that questions like this are asked often; please look for duplicates; it may be that you don't need to edit the question at all.

Comment: My point is: if my main goal was to improve the text and that was enough to meet the edition's requirement, why would put some additional stuff make it unacceptable? Thus, I don't think that this is a duplicate of the FAQ. But I think I didn't made myself clear, im editing the post.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how it is distinct from the proposed duplicate. Note that there are many other questions about this error message, e.g., [Trying to edit a question with the “It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.” error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332759/215552), [Is there a way to edit a “mostly code” question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256092/215552). According to the answers to the proposed duplicate and these other questions, the reason is that the code you are formatting as code pushes it over the "too much code" threshold.

Comment: I still think it is some kind of "corner case" of this rule. For me, it doesn't make sense if a rule will accept a suggestion but won't accept a "improved" version of the same suggestion. But maybe it is hard to make a workaround and still prevent irrelevant suggestions. Thx for the help anyway