# Is there a way to upload code on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to attach code here?

Below is the copy pasted version of the code.
// Your First Program

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Copy-pasted code is fine, but I'm curious - what are you running into when you attempt to do that?  [There *are* messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310791/1079354) that a user would get if their question is *just* code...

Comment: Are you proposing that it should be possible to run the code (there are some meta posts with such proposals)  or not?

Comment: If you mean runnable code, then see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327741/support-running-snippets-in-languages-other-than-just-javascript). If that's not what you mean, then you already answered your own question by posting this.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy paste the parts you need to put here, or if you are using HTML, CSS, or JavaScript you can add a snippet with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>. Also, if you have "```" to open a code block, you can add the language for syntax highlighting, such as

````
```java
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```
````