# Question that is "mostly code" gets asked, but can't be edited

Tags: support, bug, edits, quality-filter

I was trying to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531000/how-to-add-items-in-listbox-without-duplicate-like-that/), just to fix up grammar, punctuation, spelling etc. when this error occurred:

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

That seems reasonable and everything, so how did the question even get asked? Why does Stack Overflow let someone post a question that is "mostly code", but not allow me improving details given by the OP? Shouldn't Stack Overflow stop the question from being asked in the first place?

---

[image: Screenshot of error when editing post]

Comment: I think almost the same question was already asked and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256092/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-mostly-code-question?rq=1#comment28273_256092 comment (fluff added till filter no longer applies) is likely answer you are interested in. I voted as duplicate (as it really contains good information on what to do in this case), but indeed this one can be considered just "why it is allowed"/"how to bypass 'code-only-question' filter".

Comment: Looks like [he got "tired" trying to ask an actual question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35531000/1). No reason to waste time trying to polish crap that the asker couldn't be bothered to fix himself.

Comment: @CodyGray I totally agree, but request is that the question doesn't get asked in the _first place_.

Comment: Hmm, yeah. It is too easy to beat a naive filter. [We turned it up once already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174097/is-it-time-to-tighten-up-the-question-quality-filter), but all a determined user has to do is add nonsense text that does little to describe their problem.

Comment: @CodyGray, okay, so should I delete this post, because it is a duplicate?

Comment: You don't have to delete it just because it's a duplicate.

Comment: @CodyGray, I would like to ask another question along the same lines. But this question wouldn't ask _why_ "mostly code" questions can't be edited, or _why_ "mostly code" questions can't be asked, but rather a **feature-request** for the quality-filter to include the "mostly code" filter for both asking and editing, to stop "mostly code" questions at the source. I believe that this is not a duplicate, because [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256092/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-mostly-code-question) asks for ways around it, not for change.

Comment: @Mirabilis that prevents one success path: a person asking a low quality mostly code question, people helping the OP to make it better, and it eventually being edited into a question that is not mostly code.

Comment: @Gimby, that's a good point. I never actually thought of that :).