# Unable to submit re-tag because question appears to "..be mostly code..."

Tags: bug

I tried to re-tag a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643754/assert-middleware-is-attached-to-express-endpoint-in-unit-test) but was unable to submit it. The reason I am given is that the question appears to

> "...be mostly code..."

The question makes sense and I see not reason to edit besides improving the tagging.

It seems illogical that a question that has been accepted by the algorithm when posted by the author cannot be edited (in my case re-tagged) due to reasons that only the author can do something about. I mean if there is an algorithm determining that a "*...mostly code...*" question cannot be edited then that same algorithm should also be applied when the author tries to post the question.

In my opinion this inconsequential appliance of the algorithm can only be considered a bug.

---

My question is **not a duplicate** of this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256092/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-mostly-code-question). I am trying to *re-tag only* and the question I am trying to re-tag *do not need editing*.

Comment: I was thinking about this one all wrong.  I thought this was an older question, but it's *very* new.  Not sure how this slipped by.  However, I was able to remove the "sinon" tag since it didn't seem like the question concerned sinon at all.  It *might* be specific to your reputation, but that's anecdotal at this point until someone can find a reference to that kind of edit.

Comment: I also tried to add the tag "unit-testing" - is that also possible for you?