# When saving a post, attempt to detect unformatted code to block questions that are "mostly code" but are not correctly formatted

Tags: feature-request

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256092/12282360) asks a very similar question, but what I am trying to ask is for a system which automatically treats unformatted code:

like this:

> Import Pygame
>
> if(x ==1){
>
> doSomething(x)
>
> }

the same as formatted code like this:

> ```
> Import Pygame
>
>  if(x ==1){
>
> doSomething(x)
>
> }
> ```

so questions that are mostly code but not correctly formatted are blocked as well.

Comment: What do you mean by *"treats unformatted code"*?

Comment: @NickA I believe that the reason why the original poster is able to post his/her question without it being detected as mostly code, is because it is not formatted in code blocks, which means when I go in and edit it into code blocks, it says 'your post is mostly code' and does not allow me to post it.

Comment: So you mean "automatically detect unformatted code as code and include it in the "too much code" heuristic"?

Comment: @yivi I more think OP meant to stop the author from posting the question in the first place until it wasn't mostly code

Comment: @yivi Agreed, although if it is what I think it is then it would make a good feature request and I can't think of a dupe for it

Comment: As I read it, it's a feature request to block ops from asking mostly code questions **no matter if they formatted it correctly or not**. Op here complains that they can't edit those posts to improve formatting because it's then mostly code.